# Limit of sequence of integrals

Tags: measure-theory, limits, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  \int _0^\infty \frac{(1-e^{-x})^n}{1+x^2}dx.$$

this is less then 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  \int _0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx.$$
so the limit should exist by DCT.
But how do I calculate:
$$  \int _0^\infty  \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{(1-e^{-x})^n}{1+x^2}dx$$

Comment: Isn't $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{(1-e^{-x})^n}{1+x^2} = 0 $ ?

Comment: $$\forall x>0\;,\;\;0<1-e^{-x}<1\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}(1-e^{-x})^n=0$$

Comment: that was not to complicated, thanks

Comment: @Donantonio , the sequence is positive so you are passing the limit inside , right?

Comment: "that was not to(o) complicated"... Hmmm. Better though to add some monotonicity or some domination in the pot, otherwise the proof is incomplete.

Comment: I agree with Did.  For example you can have $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x+n} dx = \infty$ even though $\lim_{n \to \infty} 1/(x+n) = 0$ for all $x \geq 0$.

Comment: I think we need some [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) up in here.  Using $g = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ as per Johan and DonAntonio's observation should be sufficient.

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai, I don't understand what you mean "passing the limit inside". I just observed that **sequence's** limit is zero. To get the limit inside the integral one needs more, of course...but that was already done before.

Answer (score 1):

Following the argument of Bertrand R and DonAntonio, for all $x > 0$ we have $0 < (1 - e^{-x}) < 1$ and therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1 - e^{-x})^n = 0$. So
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\infty \frac{(1 - e^{-x})^n}{1 + x^2} \mathrm dx
\overset{\text{DCT}}{=}\int_0^\infty\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(1 - e^{-x})^n}{1 + x^2} \mathrm dx
= \int_0^\infty 0 \;\mathrm dx
= 0.
$$